# Problema con Edittext dentro Listview

Tags: android

Buenas tardes

Ya estoy terminando un app en Android Studio, ya solo estoy detallando, pero me encuentro con un detalle que no lo he podido resolver, lo que pasa es que tengo una `listview` con una vista personalizada, en la cual en la vista personalizada tengo un `Edittext` para que el usuario ponga una cantidad y en la parte de abajo un boton para grabar la cantidad y mandarla por webservices.

Pero el problema es que cuando me quiero posicionar sobre el `Edittext` que lo tengo como type númerico, no me muestra el cursor en el`Edittext`por lo cual no me muestra el teclado numérico, si lo coloco en Landscape si me muestra el keyboard sin problemas...

La aplicación la emulo usando Genymotion, les anexo una imagen.

Les dejo mi código del `layout` y de mi `activity`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/Folio"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColor="#060000"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="FOLIO FACTURA"
        android:id="@+id/txtFolio"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/Fecha"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColor="#060000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="58dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="58dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtFolio"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtFolio" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="FECHA"
        android:id="@+id/txtFecha"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtFolio"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/Total"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/Saldo_total"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/Saldo_Vencidode"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_column="7"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="0.00"
            android:id="@+id/total"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="0.00"
            android:id="@+id/txttotal"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#090808"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="0.00"
            android:id="@+id/txtvencido"
            android:layout_column="7"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#f90a0a"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hint_abono"
            android:id="@+id/edt_abono"
            android:layout_column="20"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Activity

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Detalle_Cliente extends AppCompatActivity{
ProgressDialog dialog;
TextView resultado;
ListView list;
ArrayList<DetalleCxP> DetalleArrayList = new ArrayList<DetalleCxP>();
MyArrayAdapter adaptador;
AlertDialog alert = null;
CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor O_Cliente;
DetalleMenu O_DetalleMenu;

private TextView lblLatitud;
private TextView lblLongitud;
private LocationManager locManager;
private LocationListener locListener;
TextView direccion;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent1=getIntent();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalle__cliente);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Inicializan datos de ubicacion
    lblLatitud = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LblPosLatitud);
    lblLongitud = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LblPosLongitud);
    lblLongitud.getTag();
    direccion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.direccion);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Aqui van los comentarions",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    Intent intentt=getIntent();
    O_DetalleMenu=(DetalleMenu) intentt.getSerializableExtra("O_DetalleMenu");

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    O_Cliente=(CXCPSaldoClienteProveedor) intent.getSerializableExtra("O_Cliente");
    setTitle(O_Cliente.getClienteDescripcion());
    //codigo listview
    list=(ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listDeta);
    comenzarLocalizacion();
    AsyncCallWSDetalle task = new AsyncCallWSDetalle();
    //Call execute
    task.execute();

    //Codigo Boton de Pagar
    Button pagar = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnpago);
    pagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Detalle_Cliente.this);
            alert.setMessage("¿Estas Seguro de Aplicar el Abono?");
                    alert.setTitle("Confirmacion");

                    alert.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()  {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            comenzarLocalizacion();
                            AsyncGrabarCXCP task = new AsyncGrabarCXCP();


                            //Call execute
                            task.execute();
                        }
                    });
                    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            alert.show();
            //Validar();
          // adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}


private void comenzarLocalizacion() {
    //Obtenemos una referencia al LocationManager
    locManager =
            (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //Obtenemos la última posición conocida
    Location loc =
            locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    //Mostramos la última posición conocida
    mostrarPosicion(loc);

    //Nos registramos para recibir actualizaciones de la posición
    locListener = new LocationListener() {


        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if(location.getLatitude() != 0.0D && location.getLongitude() != 0.0D) {
                try {
                    Geocoder e = new Geocoder(Detalle_Cliente.this, Locale.getDefault());
                    List list = e.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                    if(!list.isEmpty()) {
                        Address DirCalle = (Address)list.get(0);
                        direccion.setText("Mi direccion es: \n" + DirCalle.getAddressLine(0));
                    }
                } catch (IOException var5) {
                    var5.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            //lblEstado.setText("Provider OFF");
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            //lblEstado.setText("Provider ON ");
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            /*Log.i("", "Provider Status: " + status);
            lblEstado.setText("Provider Status: " + status);*/
        }
    };

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1500, 0, locListener);
}

private void mostrarPosicion(Location loc) {
    if(loc != null)
    {
        lblLatitud.setText("Latitud: " + String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()));
        lblLongitud.setText("Longitud: " + String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));
        //lblPrecision.setText("Precision: " + String.valueOf(loc.getAccuracy()));
        Log.i("", String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude() + " - " + String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude())));
    }
    else
    {
        lblLatitud.setText("Latitud: (sin_datos)");
        lblLongitud.setText("Longitud: (sin_datos)");
        //lblPrecision.setText("Precision: (sin_datos)");
    }
}





//Codigo Para Grabar docuemnto
private class AsyncCallWSDetalle extends AsyncTask<String, ArrayList, ArrayList> {


    @Override
    protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params){
        DetalleArrayList=webService.DetalleCxP(O_Cliente.getCliente());
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    //Make Progress Bar visible
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        dialog=new ProgressDialog(Detalle_Cliente.this);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Cargando Detalle...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(ArrayList... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    //Once WebService returns response
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList) {
        super.onPostExecute(arrayList);
        if(DetalleArrayList.size()!=0){
            dialog.dismiss();

            adaptador= new MyArrayAdapter(Detalle_Cliente.this, DetalleArrayList);///* no se usa your_array_list

            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listDeta);
            listView.setAdapter(adaptador);
            adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }else{
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}




public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DetalleCxP> {


    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DetalleCxP> ArrayClientes) {
        super(context, 0, ArrayClientes);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        DetalleCxP O_DetalleCxP = getItem(position);

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_detalle, parent, false);
            EditText ET_Abono = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono);
            //attach the TextWatcher listener to the EditText
            ET_Abono.addTextChangedListener(new TB_Abono_Watcher(convertView));
        }

        //Obteniendo instancias de los text views
        TextView fecha = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFecha);
        TextView folio = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFolio);
        TextView vencido = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvencido);
        TextView saldo = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txttotal);
        EditText Abono = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono);
        TextView total = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.total);


        DecimalFormat numberFormat  = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        fecha.setText(dateFormat.format(O_DetalleCxP.getFecha()));


        folio.setText(O_DetalleCxP.getFolio());

        Abono.setTag(O_DetalleCxP);
        if (O_DetalleCxP.TotalAplicado>0)
        {
            Abono.setText(numberFormat.format(O_DetalleCxP.TotalAplicado));
        }
        else
        {
            Abono.setText("");
        }
        total.setText(numberFormat.format(O_DetalleCxP.getTotal()));
        saldo.setText(numberFormat.format(O_DetalleCxP.getSaldo()));
        vencido.setText(numberFormat.format(O_DetalleCxP.getSaldoVencido()));




        //Devolver al ListView la fila creada
        return convertView;


    }
}



//Clae para Edittext
private class TB_Abono_Watcher implements TextWatcher{


    Button pagar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnpago);
    private View view;
    private TB_Abono_Watcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        /*if(s.toString().trim().length()==0){
            pagar.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            pagar.setEnabled(true);
        }*/



        //do nothing
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //do nothing
    }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {

        EditText ET_Abono = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_abono);
        DetalleCxP O_DetalleCxP = (DetalleCxP)ET_Abono.getTag();
        O_DetalleCxP.TotalAplicado=ONC_SYS.NullToZeroDouble(s.toString());

    }
}


//Medoto para Grabar datos



 public class AsyncGrabarCXCP extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,String>
    {
        int Recurso;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog=new ProgressDialog(Detalle_Cliente.this);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Procesando Datos...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
       String Resultado="";

       Recurso=webService.ObtenerRecurso();
       String Folio = webService.ObtenerFolio(35);
       Date O_D = new Date();

       Double Factor=0.0, Importe=0.0, Descuento=0.0, SubTotal=0.0, Total=0.0, IVA=0.0,Retencion1=0.0,Retencion2=0.0,IEPS=0.0;

       Double DFactor=0.0;

       for(int i=0;i<DetalleArrayList.size();i++) {

           Factor=0.0;

           if (((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).TotalAplicado>0)
            {
                Factor = ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).TotalAplicado / ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Total;

                Importe += ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Importe*Factor;
                Descuento += ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Descuento*Factor;
                SubTotal += ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).SubTotal*Factor;
                IVA += ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).IVA*Factor;
                Retencion1 += ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Retencion1*Factor;
                Retencion2 += ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Retencion2*Factor;
                IEPS += ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).IEPS*Factor;
                Total += ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Total*Factor;

                String resultado=String.valueOf(Total);

            }

       }


        Resultado = webService.LLenarEncabezadoCXCP(Recurso,
                                       "I",    //Accion I
                                        0,      //Id = 0
                                        O_Cliente.getEmpresa(), //Id de Empresa
                                        Folio,
                                        new Date(),
                                        O_Cliente.getCliente(),
                                        O_Cliente.getProveedor(),
                                        O_Cliente.getMoneda(),
                                        1.0,      //Tipo de Cambio por default 1
                                        0,      //Cuenta Bancaria
                                        "hugo", //Usuario Captura
                                        6,          //Pago Forma
                                        Total,          //Saldo
                                        Importe,    //Importe
                                        0,          //Financiamiento
                                        Descuento,
                                        SubTotal,
                                        Retencion1,
                                        Retencion2,
                                        IEPS,
                                        IVA,
                                        0,          //ISH,
                                        Total,      //Total
                                        Total,      //totalaplicado,
                                        "A",        //status,
                                        "",         //usucariocancela,
                                        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,   //Numero1...Numero10
                                        "","","","","","","","","","",                      //Texto1...Texto10
                                        new Date(),new Date(),new Date(),new Date(),new Date(),new Date(),  //Fecha1...Texto6
                                        "",         //Observacion
                                        0,0,0,0,0,0,         //Catalogo1...Catalogo6
                                        "",         //ordencompra
                                        0,          //concepto
                                        "",         //observacioncancelacion
                                        0,          //origenventacompra,
                                        0           //origeninventario
                                        );
        if (Resultado.equals("OK"))
        {

            for(int i=0;i<DetalleArrayList.size();i++) {



                if (((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).TotalAplicado>0)
                {
                    DFactor = ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).TotalAplicado / ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Total;


                    Resultado = webService.LLenarDetalleCXCP(Recurso,
                            "I", //Accion
                            0, //id
                            ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).getId(),  //Origen
                            ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).getDocumento(),  //OrigenDocumento
                            (Double)(((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Importe*DFactor),   //Importe
                            (Double)0.0,  //Financiamiento
                            (Double)(((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Descuento*DFactor), //Descuento
                            (Double)(((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).SubTotal*DFactor),   //Subtotal
                            (Double)(((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Retencion1*DFactor), //Retencion1
                            (Double)(((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Retencion2*DFactor),  //Retencion2
                            (Double)(((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).IEPS*DFactor),   //IEPS
                            (Double)(((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).IVA*DFactor), //IVA
                            (Double)0.0, //ISH
                            (Double)(((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).Total*DFactor),  //Total
                            ((DetalleCxP)DetalleArrayList.get(i)).getSaldo(),   //Saldo
                            "Android App"      //Referencia
                    );

                }

            }

        }


        if (Resultado.equals("OK"))

        {

            Resultado = webService.GrabarCxCP(Recurso,//Recurso
                            O_DetalleMenu.getModulo(),      //Modulo
                            O_DetalleMenu.getOperacion(),      //Operacion
                            O_DetalleMenu.getDocumento(),      //Documento
                            0,      //OrigenId
                            0);     //OrigenDocumento
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String Resultado) {
        super.onPostExecute(Resultado);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Datos Guardados Correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
       /* if ((Resultado == "OK"))
        {
            try {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Datos Guardado Correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error en el Webservices" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }*/
    }

public DetalleCxP FindCXCPSaldoClienteProveedorById(int Id)
{
    for(int i=0;i<DetalleArrayList.size();i++)
    {
        if (DetalleArrayList.get(i).getId()==Id)
        {
            return DetalleArrayList.get(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y en un dispositivo físico lo has probado? no es recomendable usar 100% el emulador para determinar fallos y sacar la app a producción.

Comment: si le he probado fisicamente, pero ya quedo solucionado...

Comment: Pues marca la respuesta como solventada, o bien añade tu solución

Answer (score 0):

Probá con esto:

```
InputMethodManager imm;
imm = (InputMethodManager)this.getSystemService(getApplicationContext().INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
TuEditetText = (EditetTExt) findViewById(R.id.TuEditetText);
```

Y luego:

```
    TuEditetText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                    if(FrameKeyboard.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){

                        TuEditetText.requestFocus();
                        imm.showSoftInput(TuEditetText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

                    }

                }
                return false;
            }
})
```